# MP4Box MP4 concatenation not working

Tags: mp4, ubuntu-15.04, mp4box

I download lectures in mp4 format from Udacity, but they're often broken down into 2-5 minute chunks. I'd like to combine the videos for each lecture into one continuous stream, which I've had success with on Windows using AnyVideo Converter. I'm trying to do the same thing on Ubuntu 15, and most of my web search results suggest MP4Box, whose documentation and all the online examples I can find offer the following syntax:

```
MP4Box -cat vid1.mp4 -cat vid2.mp4 -cat vid3.mp4 -new combinedfile.mp4
```

This creates a new file with working audio, but the video doesn't work. When I open with Ubuntu's native video player, I get the error "No valid frames decoded before end of stream." When I open with VLC, I get the error "Codec not supported: VLC could not decode the format 'avc3' (No description for this codec." I've tried using the `-keepsys` switch, as well, but I get the same results.

All the documentation and online discussion makes it sound as though what I'm trying to do is and should be really simple, but I can't seem to find info relevant to the specific errors I'm getting. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `-force-cat` option.

For example,

```
MP4Box -force-cat -add in1.mp4 -cat in2.mp4 -cat in3.mp4 ... -new out.mp4
```

From the MP4Box documentation:

```
-force-cat
       skips media configuration check when concatenating file.
```

Comment: This worked! Can you please explain why?

The documentation says,
`-force-cat
              skips media configuration check when concatenating file.`

I'm not sure how that works.

Answer (score 1):

It looks, by the presence of `'avc3'`, that these videos are encoded with h.264|avc. There are several modes for the concatenation of such streams. Either the video streams have compatible encoder configurations (frame size, ...) in which case only one configuration description is used in the file (signaled by 'avc1'). If the configurations are not fully compatible, MP4Box uses the 'inband' storage of those configurations (signaled by 'avc3'). The other way would be to use multiple sample description entries (stream configurations) but that is not well supported by players and not yet possible with MP4Box. There is no other way unless you want to reencode your videos. On Ubuntu, you should be able to play 'avc3' streams with the player that goes with MP4Box: MP4Client.